# converting from xml name-values into simple hash

Tags: ruby, xml, yaml, rexml

I don't know what name this goes by and that's been complicating my search.

My data file *OX.session.xml* is in the (old?) form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CAppLogin xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://oxbranch.optionsxpress.com">
  <SessionID>FE5E27A056944FBFBEF047F2B99E0BF6</SessionID>
  <AccountNum>8228-5500</AccountNum>
  <AccountID>967454</AccountID>
</CAppLogin>
```

What is that XML data format called exactly?

Anyway, all I want is to end up with one hash in my Ruby code like so:

```
CAppLogin = { :SessionID => "FE5E27A056944FBFBEF047F2B99E0BF6", :AccountNum => "8228-5500", etc. }   # Doesn't have to be called CAppLogin as in the file, may be fixed
```

What might be shortest, most built-in Ruby way to automate that hash read, in a way I can update the SessionID value and store it easily back into the file for later program runs?

I've played around with YAML, REXML but would rather not yet print my (bad) example trials.

Comment: It's called XML binding (mapping XML to objects in another language) or XML conversion!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a few libraries you can use in Ruby to do this.

Ruby toolbox has some good coverage of a few of them:

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/xml_mapping

I use XMLSimple, just require the gem then load in your xml file using xml_in:

```
require 'xmlsimple'
hash = XmlSimple.xml_in('session.xml')
```

If you're in a Rails environment, you can just use Active Support:

```
require 'active_support' 
session = Hash.from_xml('session.xml')
```

Comment: `gem install xml-simple` Thanks, I'll check if there's as simple a `.xml_out` method to save it right back to the file...

Comment: Yep, xml_out will take a data structure (Hash, in your case), and return it in XML encoding.

Answer (score 8):

Using [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) to parse the XML with namespaces:

```
require 'nokogiri'

dom = Nokogiri::XML(File.read('OX.session.xml'))

node = dom.xpath('ox:CAppLogin',
                 'ox' => "http://oxbranch.optionsxpress.com").first

hash = node.element_children.each_with_object(Hash.new) do |e, h|
  h[e.name.to_sym] = e.content
end

puts hash.inspect
# {:SessionID=>"FE5E27A056944FBFBEF047F2B99E0BF6",
#  :AccountNum=>"8228-5500", :AccountID=>"967454"}
```

If you *know* that the CAppLogin is the root element, you can simplify a bit:

```
require 'nokogiri'

dom = Nokogiri::XML(File.read('OX.session.xml'))

hash = dom.root.element_children.each_with_object(Hash.new) do |e, h|
  h[e.name.to_sym] = e.content
end

puts hash.inspect
# {:SessionID=>"FE5E27A056944FBFBEF047F2B99E0BF6",
#  :AccountNum=>"8228-5500", :AccountID=>"967454"}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like your second example better since I don't know/don't want to care what the name of the root element will be, which contains the actual key/value pairs I need to edit and save back into the file somehow.