# Read XML responses in to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a URL in my controller that when called return an XML response. Let say, the response looks like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AutoCreate>
<Response>
    <Status>YES</Status>
    <name>JOSEPH</name>
    <location>HOME</location>
</Response>
</AutoCreate>
```

How can i read these values `status`, `name` and `location` into variables in my controller and use them.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139709/converting-from-xml-name-values-into-simple-hash)

Answer (score 1):

can you try this,

```
response_json = Hash.from_xml(response).to_json
```

Answer (score 1):

So heres an update for Rails 5,

If you are receiving an XML response the header will be 'application/xml'
You access the data using

```
#read the response and create a Hash from the XML
response = Hash.from_xml(request.body.read)

#read value from the Hash
status = response["AutoCreate"]["Response"]["Status"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value of respose.body is;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AutoCreate>
<Response>
    <Status>YES </Status>
    <name> JOSEPH </name>
    <location> HOME </location>
</Response>
</AutoCreate>
```

Then i think this should be fine.

```
require ‘active_support’ 
result = Hash.from_xml(response.body)
```

then;

```
result.status  == "YES"
```

Would this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/alsemyonov/xommelier

```
feed = Xommelier::Atom::Feed.parse(open('spec/fixtures/feed.atom.xml'))
puts feed.id, feed.title, feed.updated

feed.entries do |entry|
  puts feed.id, feed.title, feed.published, feed.updated
  puts feed.content || feed.summary
end
```