# How can I convert xml into json in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, xml

```
<result>
    <sequence id="148"></sequence>
    <sequence id="211"></sequence>
    <sequence id="81">!Kyle OP Test</sequence>
    <sequence id="197">(SS) AnikSIB - 1 Hour Reminder</sequence>
    <sequence id="198">(SS) AnikSIB - 5 minutes Reminder</sequence>
<result>
```

How can I convert the above xml into json I want sequence id like 148 ,211,81,197 and !Kyle OP Test ,(SS) AnikSIB - 1 Hour Reminder
What I am trying : `Hash.from_xml(xmlresponce)`
And my Output is:

```
{
  "result": {
    "sequence": [
      {
        "id": "148"
      },
      {
        "id": "211"
      },
      "!Kyle OP Test",
      "(SS) AnikSIB - 1 Hour Reminder",
      "(SS) AnikSIB - 5 minutes Reminder",
```

I want the sequence id of `!Kyle OP Test` which I am not getting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [converting from xml name-values into simple hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139709/converting-from-xml-name-values-into-simple-hash)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby XML to JSON Converter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530324/ruby-xml-to-json-converter)

Answer (score 0):

To deal with XML documents in professional manner, one uses [`nokogiri`](http://www.nokogiri.org/)

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(input) # XML document

doc.xpath("//sequence[text()='!Kyle OP Test']") # query for nodes with text
   .first                                       # first, since it’s unique
   .xpath("@id")                                # get attribute
   .first                                       # first, yeah
   .value                                       # value
#⇒ "81"
```